# Xamarin.Android can't get GridLayout items width to equally divide

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, grid-layout

Im trying to add buttons in a GridLayout with 3 columns but the dont divide equally. The GridLayout matches parent width correctly. I have tried setting gravity and layout_width but to no success. How will it equally divide[image]

```
<GridLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout1">
        <Button
            android:text="0"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:background="#ff8fc4f1"
            android:textColor="#ff353535"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
             />
```

Comment: If you add your current code, I'll fix it for you.

Comment: I havent added any code myself, this is the xml generated

`<GridLayout
   android:minWidth="25px"
   android:minHeight="25px"
   android:columnCount="3"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/gridLayout1">
   <Button
    android:text="0"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:background="#ff8fc4f1"
    android:textColor="#ff353535"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
     />
`

Comment: you have this tagged as Xamarin Forms, but your code is for Xamarin Android.  You'll get better responses if you tag your post correctly

Comment: Are you sure you have the right tags? It looks like you're mixing Forms with native Android...

Comment: I've changed the tags, sorry

Comment: Tried googling options still no success. Does xamarin really lack a simple feature like this?